# Benefit of neon_vector_type over vector_size?

Tags: c++, c, clang, simd, neon

clang ang clang++ support [several different flavors of vectors](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors) in addition to normal GCC-style vectors (using the `vector_size` attribute).  `ext_vector_type` supports some additional syntax, and `neon_polyvector_type` does carryless multiplication, but what does `neon_vector_type` offer that `vector_size` doesn't?

AFAICT `neon_vector_type` [generates the same machine code](https://godbolt.org/z/kB5VVL) as `vector_size`.  It has some limitations that `vec_size` doesn't, such as only working on ARM when NEON is enabled, only supporting 64-bit and 128-bit vectors, only working on clang, etc., so the only thing I've thought of is that maybe the whole point is to make sure you don't mistakenly think your code is running fast, but I have trouble believing that is the reason for it (although it could make for a useful diagnostic).